# How do I run a shell script from rpm during the build process?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

Basically I want my build process to do this:

1. **Run a shell script that strips data from csv files and combines them into a single csv.**
2. **The resulting csv output from that script is then packaged in the rpm.**
3. **When rpm -install is run, the csv file (not the script) is placed in a specific location on the target machine.**

I'm very new to RPM so I'm sorry if I've made a blunder with the code below, but it gives me several errors when trying to build or install.

I attempted to run a script from the sources directory

I'm a little confused on how the expected flow of rpm should work. In testing, I'm building and installing on the same machine, but in practice it will be on two machines.

When I run the code below, does it put a copy of my source files into the .rpm file?
I'm wondering why it doesn't work. **(it says process.sh does not exist)**

```
Name:       Test
Version:    1
Release:    1
Summary:    Test
License:    FIXME


%description
this is a test build

%prep
echo "BUILDROOT = $RPM_BUILD_ROOT"
mkdir -p -m777 $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin/
cp /home/myuser/foo/util/* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin
cd $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/local/bin/
./process.sh hosts.csv processed.csv
exit

%files
%attr(0777, root, root) /foo/processed.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- Set up the build tree for your user, e.g. run `rpmdev-setuptree`
- Place the source files to `SOURCES` in the build tree
- Declare some `Source` tags. It is crucial for a proper build. Because this is how you reference the files that make up your build, during the build.

E.g.

```
Source0: process.sh
Source1: util.tar.gz
```

The `util.tar.gz` can be the tarball for all the numerous CSV files (I assume there are too many, so it would be not feasible to have an individual `Source` entry for each of them.

Then:

- in the `%prep` section you would extract `%{SOURCE1}`.
- in the `%build` section you can combine them into a single file
- in the `%install` section you would install the combined file

```
%prep
cp -p %{SOURCE0} .
tar zxvf %{SOURCE1}

# ...

%install
%{__mkdir} -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/%{name}
%{__install} -m 644 -p processed.csv \
    $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_datadir}/%{name}/

%files
%{_datadir}/%{name}/processed.csv
```

P.S. I know for a beginner it would sound a bit an unnecessary task to copy something to the `SOURCES` directory when you already have it elsewhere, but this is the way to go still.

Comment: thanks for the reply. How do I reference the newly created file that was made during %build? The file won't exist until the shell script creates it so I'm unsure of how to make a copy of it from within rpm

Comment: The newly created file is created during the build. You don't need to reference it in the `Source`, instead, it must be referenced in the `%files` section because you want to package it. See additions to the answer. In both `%build` and `%install` sections, `rpmbuild` will first `cd` to `BUILD` directory (so you can reference the created file just by its name).

Comment: so I tried to do what you suggested, but now it seems that I can't execute the shell script during the build process. I looked at the log and after the %prep section is completed its deleting all of the newly copied files..

Comment: See update. You also need to copy the sources to the build directory.

Comment: I know this is asking alot, but could you show me an example of build as well? I've tried exactly what you have pretty much and a million  other iterations but it keeps telling me that the files don't exist. Even with just a simple shellscript that just prints hello world is fine, I can't get my script to run at all.

Comment: You can paste your build log somewhere (pastebin?), so we can see what it's going wrong.

Comment: @Remixt see here for something that builds without error: https://github.com/dvershinin/stackoverflow-62073308 (anything other than spec file you'd place to `SOURCES`)

Comment: @Danilla Vershinin I finally was able to get it to run. Apparently my shell script was not encoded properly so it was giving me a file not found error.